# How do you test observables in the ngOnInit lifecycle?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular2-observables

I've seen tons of articles on testing observables, including [writing marble tests](https://medium.com/@bencabanes/marble-testing-observable-introduction-1f5ad39231c) and somehow I still can't find a straight answer on how to test a simple observable in my component in my ngOnInit cycle.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selectedMembers$.subscribe((members) => {
        if (!!members) {
            this.store.dispatch(actions.getPCPs());
        }
    });

    this.membersForm.valueChanges.subscribe((id) => {
        if (!!id.member_id) {
            if (id.member_id === 'null') {
                this.store.dispatch(actions.getMembers());

                return;
            }
            this.store.dispatch(
                actions.getSelectedMember({ member_id: id.member_id }),
            );
        }
    });

    this.config$.subscribe((config) => {
        if (!!config) {
            config.mobile_filters.controls.forEach((control) => {
                this.formControlService.addControlToFormGroup(
                    this.mobileFiltersForm,
                    control,
                );
            });
        }
    });
}
```

In there a straight forward way to spyOn this component and check that these observables are emitting something?

```
 it('should test observables in ngOnInit', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(component.selectedMembers$, 'subscribe')
    let myData;
    component.selectedMembers$.subscribe((data) => {
        myData = data;
        console.log('data',data);
        expect(myData).toEqual(data);
    })
}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want to test exactly?

If you just want your subscribe callback to be called before your test finishes, you could use the `tick()` method in your test (https://angular.io/api/core/testing/tick):

```
it('should dispatch if members are provided / selected', fakeAsync(() => {
  // arrange
  const dispatchSpy = spyOn(component.store, 'dispatch');
  const membersToEmit = ['member-1', 'member-2'];
  component.selectedMembers$ = of(membersToEmit) // of from 'rxjs';

  // act
  component.ngOnInit();
  // alternatively you could call:
  // fixture.detectChanges();

  tick();  // causes your Observable to emit, so that the subscribe callback gets called 

  // assert
  expect(dispatchSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

Comment: In this test the call of `tick()` is not necessary since Observable.subscribe() runs "synchronously and immediately" as it is stated in https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/scheduler:

"By default, a subscribe() call on an Observable will happen synchronously and immediately."

Comment: I had to add `jasmine.getEnv().allowRespy(true);` but it appears that this approach works. Will give you credit for the credit answer once I finish testing.

Comment: Ok, Glad to hear that. `jasmine.getEnv().allowRespy(true);`is totally new to me but it sounds like that it allows to create spies for the same function multiple times which is not possible by default. You should check if you have already created a spy on component.store.dispatch, maybe somewhere else in your test code. I can also help you to spot the potential redundant spy when you share some more code from you test.

Answer (score 0):

For example this part:

```
this.selectedMembers$.subscribe((members) => {
    if (!!members) {
        this.store.dispatch(actions.getPCPs());
    }
});
```

In your test:

```
const spy = spyOn(store, 'dispatch');
component.selectedMembers$.next('abc');
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('abc');
```

Are you asking something like this ?

Comment: Yea, I want to test the function. When I enter your code I have two problems. store is an observable and it states 'cannot find name store' I have Store imported up top. I'm not sure what the lowercase store is. Also, for next `Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable<Member[]>'.